# Magento 2.0 installing Error always_populate_raw_post_data

Tags: php, apache, magento, php-ini, php-5.6

I am trying to install Magento 2.0 on my Server. During the Installation process, at the version check screen, there is the following error:

[image: Screenshot Magento 2.0 installation]

My server is on OpenSuse 13.2 with PHP 5.6.1.

In my `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` is the following line:

```
always_populate_raw_post_data = -1
```

I restarted Apache already.

**Edit**

I also tried it with `always_populate_raw_post_data = "-1"` AND `always_populate_raw_post_data = 0`. For default it was like `;always_populate_raw_post_data = 0`.

I run the install script via Google Chrome.

Comment: try to just comment that line like this `;always_populate_raw_post_data = On` yes that should work,, I have magento 2 installed like that :)

Comment: this doesnt work for me.

Comment: we are not on same version of php, I'm on PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14.. and I installed it ok

Comment: remove the comment `;` in front and try `always_populate_raw_post_data = -1` and restart apache service once

Comment: i already tried this one and the error is still there i also reboot the whole server for this with the setting  always_populate_raw_post_data = -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` is the following line:

This config file only affects `php` run from the command line (`/cli/`), and you said you're running it from Apache.

To edit the version Apache uses, you'll need to edit a different file. On OpenSUSE, it should be `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`. If you're using Apache with PHP FastCGI Process Manager, it would be `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`. You can then set `always_populate_raw_post_data` to `1` or `On`.

Note that this will not work in PHP 7.0+ as `always_populate_raw_post_data` no longer exists in PHP 7; you're stuck with 5.6.x for now. Hopefully Magento will fix the issue in an upcoming release.

To find your Apache `php.ini` path on any system, you can also put a file in the root directory of your webserver called `index.php` with the following contents:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

And it will output PHP's runtime configuration, including it's path to `php.ini`.

Comment: wow, that is embarrassing ...    /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini did work for me. with    always_populate_raw_post_data = -1 Thank you.

Comment: PS: it was commented with ";" Magento need to set it to -1 / as off.